# ExportAsFixedFormat not fitting to page

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm creating a script that creates multiple xlsx files at the end of the script it will transform those xlsx files into pdf's and then delete the xlsx files everything is currently working however if I open the xlsx files they are formatted correctly in a way that you can print them in one page however the pdf is separated into 2 pages can anyone help me fit everything to one? I'm using xlsxwriter to write and format the excel files, xlwings, and win32com to convert to pdf.

```
import time
import glob
import os
import xlwings as xw

files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    files.append(file)  
for file in files:
    print(file)
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    book = xw.Book(f'{file}')
    sheet = book.sheets[0]
    current_work_dir = os.getcwd()
    pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, f"{file}.pdf")
    time.sleep(.5)
    book.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path, IgnorePrintAreas=False)
    time.sleep(.5)
    book.close()
    app.kill()

while True:
    for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
        if file == "":
            break
        else:
            os.remove(file)
```

Comment: One thing that might affect this is the paper size/type in the XlsxWriter file. It is probably best to set the paper type explicitly to "Letter" or "A4" depending on what you/Excel expects. See the XlsxWriter [worksheet.set_paper()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/page_setup.html#worksheet-set-paper) method.

Comment: I solved this issue apprently I had to change the size of the columns specifically for pdf but now im getting the following error when I trying to generate the pdf ywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)